# How do I publish a project created on Visual Studio to the web?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I am a beginner in programming and I got a few questions that I hope the experienced coders here can help me out. Please bear with me as I am a **noob** in programming.

I have created a project (ASPX) in visual studio 2015 with several HTML pages and functions. I have been trying to figure out how to publish this to the web so that maybe my friends can access it from their home. I have tried searching online but it just left me more confused. Please guide me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Q_tm9ZfGRA) for publishing WebForm(.apsx) project.Take a look at it. OR

1. [Links](https://forums.asp.net/t/2006848.aspx?How%20to%20publish%20only%20one%20aspx%20asp%20net%20web%20form%20that%20has%20changed)